# login page can't reference other files without being logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2005

I have a very strange problem. (fyi - I'm using forms authentication and manually creating a non persistant auth. ticket/cookie.) My login page has images and CSS applied to it. When I run my site locally (start without debugging), it brings up my login page, but none of my images are displaying and my css isn't linking. I'm referencing correctly, I promise.
 However, when I view this page in VS's Design view, it shows the images and CSS. Also, if I run it and log in, and click the back button, everything shows up (images/css)! But if I logout (which redirects me to the login page), my images/css isn't there! Its as if the page can't reference its own resources unless the user is logged in. WTH. I'm only having this problem on my local VS server; it seems to work fine when I put it on the live server (woot). Anyone know why this is happening?
Here is a portion of my login page that is requesting the image/css:

```
...
<head runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/BodyLayout.css" />
  <title>Optoma USA - Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <div style="text-align:left; width:990px; height:780px; background-color:White;">
  <div id="divBody">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" target="_self">
    <center>
      <div style="height:100px; width:600px; text-align:center;">
        <img src="images/Optoma_Logo.gif" alt="Unable to display image." />
      </div>
    </center>
...
```

also, here is my authorization code in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/index.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" path="/">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <!--<authorization>:-->
        <authorization>
            <!-- <deny>: will deny all users and redirect to login page,
            unless they are properly authenticated-->
            <deny users="?"/>
            <!--<allow>: might be configured later. probably will not need-->
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are making the request for the images/css, the server sees no one is logged in, so those requests get redirected to the login page. You need to place the needed images/css in a part of your app that doesn't require authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your web.config contains

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

This means users cannot load anything other than the login page -- but not its images, stylesheets, etc. You can merge the following into web.config to make an exception for images, for example:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I posted that portion of my web.config in my edit. I think you're on to something tho.. review my edit and see whats up?

Comment: Thanks for showing your config file. Yes, you do need to merge what I suggested. And another for css.